# HP SmartArray E200i - convert one non-RAID disk to RAID-1

Tags: raid, convert, hp-smart-array

Is it possible to convert one non-RAID disk to RAID-1 by adding a disk, without losing data or reinstalling Windows Server 2003? HP ACU cannot install, so I figured to do it from BIOS, but wanted to check with you guys. I am using HP ProLiant DL360 G5 with SmartArray E200i.

Cheers,
Dusan

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to install ACU, you can start it from the bootable HP SmartStart CD (you should have received it with your server). If I remember correctly, you will find it under Maintenance section in SmartStart.

BIOS utility (ORCA) doesn't have all the features in ACU.

Comment: I'd forgotten you could do that Groo, that said I'm still worried why he can't install it properly, wonder if this means the whole PSP install failed????

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can do it but only via ACU sorry (it's just a straightforward raid migration), so the question is why can't you get ACU working...have you got the latest firmware pack and PSP?